# USB HID tool or API on OS X

Tags: macos, embedded, usb, driver, hid

I am developing a USB HID device (multimedia keyboard with custom keys) which implements the Consumer Controls Usage Page. I am able to interact with it using the [hidapi](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) library by requesting the state which comes as raw data, the HID descriptor is not used.

Is there any high-level way to interact with HID device? Is there any (cross-platform) tool or API that reads and parses the HID descriptor and produces key codes?

This is my HID descriptor:

```
HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x0C),\
HID_RI_USAGE(16, 0x200),\
HID_RI_COLLECTION(8, 0x01),\
    HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x08),\
    HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(8, 0x01),\
    HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(8, 0x03),\
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x03),\
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x01),\
    HID_RI_OUTPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_VARIABLE | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE | HID_IOF_NON_VOLATILE), \
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x01),\
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x05),\
    HID_RI_OUTPUT(8, HID_IOF_CONSTANT),\
    HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x0C),\
    HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(16, StartKey),\
    HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(16, (StartKey)+(KeysCount)),\
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, MaxKeys),\
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 16),\
    HID_RI_INPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_ARRAY | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE),\
HID_RI_END_COLLECTION(0)
```

Maybe I should modify it in some way to make the system request the device automatically?

Comment: Is 'cross platform' a requirement or an option? If you just want to talk to an HID device from an application you write then Apple have higher level APIs in IOKit. It gets more complicated if you want to write a *driver* for your device. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1370/_index.html) for roadmap/QA.

Comment: @SimonJenkins, cross-platform is an option, I just want to debug the device, I'm not writing the end software right now. Thank you for the link to the QA.

Comment: I don't work on OS X, so I'm not putting an answer. But just as an extra hint, the Signal11 HID API is a known cross-plattform library and we use it on Windows for many years  http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/